# Bad Substitution Error from Variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian

I'm trying to write a script that sorts some files, and I got it working manually in the shell (Debian, seems to be dash), but when I run the same code as a script I get "Bad substitution" from line 2 and 3;

```
#!/bin/bash
LAST_MONTH="${date +'%Y%m' -d 'last month'}"
LAST_MONTH_HYPHEN="${date +'%Y-%m' -d 'last month'}"
```

Everything I found on SO seemed to be related to different shells, so I've tried `#!/bin/sh`as well as `#!/bin/bash`. I've also tried running the script as `./filesorter.sh`, `bash filesorter.sh` and `sh filesorter.sh`, and every permutation gives me some variation on the same "bad substitution" theme

```
filesorter.sh: line 2: ${date +'%Y%m' -d 'last month'}: bad substitution
filesorter.sh: line 3: ${date +'%Y-%m' -d 'last month'}: bad substitution
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Change the curly braces to parentheses.

```
LAST_MONTH="$(date +'%Y%m' -d 'last month')"
LAST_MONTH_HYPHEN="$(date +'%Y-%m' -d 'last month')"
```

Curly braces are for variable substitution, as in `${var}`, equivalent to `$var`. Parentheses are for command substitution, as in `$(command arg1 arg2)`.

[Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) is a great tool for checking the syntax of shell scripts. When fed your script it says:

> [SC2154](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2154): `date` is referenced but not assigned (for output from commands, use `"$(date ...)"`).